# SQLAlchemy ORM Load Cols Only not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using query like this:
`user = User.query.options(load_only("email", "name")).filter(and_(User.id == id, User.status == 1)).first()`

I want to get only email and name column as an User object. But it returns all columns. 
I can't find any solutions. Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: Your `user` data model is defined (as the underlying table is) to have all fields. I think this is intended behavior to ensure model/data integrity.

Comment: Maybe http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.values will do it ?

Comment: How do you know it returns all columns? Remember, SQLAlchemy lazy loads any columns on access if it's not loaded.

Comment: Sorry for posting in old question, I am suffering from the same. Is there is any solution for this without using database session method or jbndlr's comment is the answer? @univerio Yes, it returns all the column, I am able to confirm in my use case.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram How have you confirmed it? Just saying "it doesn't work" is not much to go on. I'd recommend posting a new question with details about your specific situation as it's likely that either your situation is not the same as OP's or whatever you did to confirm it is incorrect.

Comment: @univerio Yes I raised it already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736047/sqlalchemy-orm-to-load-specific-columns-in-model-query)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a database session, you can simply specify the columns directly.

`session.query(User.email, User.name).filter(and_(User.id == id, User.status == 1)).first()`